# grep regex start with, end with and contain a word

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need extract blocks (between two words: **Start** and **End**) of text containing an **other word (id)**.

For example:

```
2014-07-01 13:26:07,760 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,762 id: 456456454
2014-07-01 13:26:07,763 other
2014-07-01 13:26:07,764 End
2014-07-01 13:26:07,764 aaaaaaaa
2014-07-01 13:26:07,764 bbbbbbbb
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 id: 930939023
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 something
2014-07-01 13:26:07,766 End
2014-07-01 13:26:07,766 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,766 id: 876542
2014-07-01 13:26:07,766 other
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 End
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 aaaaaaaa
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 bbbbbbbb
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 id: 930939023
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 something
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 End
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 id: 54654
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 something
2014-07-01 13:26:07,769 End
```

For id = 930939023, the output is

```
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 id: 930939023
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 something
2014-07-01 13:26:07,766 End
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 id: 930939023
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 something
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 End
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an option using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/Start/{:a;/End/!{N;ba};/930939023/!d;p}' file
```

#### Explanation:

```
sed -n '                  # Suppress default printing
    /Start/ {             # When line contains Start
        :a;               # Create a label a for loop
        /End/! {          # Until a line with End is seen
            N;            # Append the next line to pattern space
            ba            # Go back to label a and repeat
        }
        /930939023/!d;    # If the appended line contains does not contain id, delete it
        p                 # Else print it
 }' file
```

Comment: +1 for impressive sed-fu — I need to learn these tools someday. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`. Because the script will get more complicated I suggest to store it in a file:

*extract.awk:*

```
# Set flag if id was found
/id: 930939023/{f=1}

# On "Start" clear the buffer, reset buffer index i and reset flag
/Start/{b=$0;f=0;next}

# On "End", if the flag was set print the buffer
/End/{
    if(f){
        print b
        print
    }
}

# Append all other lines to buffer
# (Lines between start end will get cleared on next "Start")
{b=b"\n"$0}
```

... and execute it like this:

```
awk -f extract.awk file
```

Output:

```
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 id: 930939023
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 something
2014-07-01 13:26:07,766 End
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 id: 930939023
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 something
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 End
```

Comment: Is there a way to include words Start/End in the command ? The blocks may have 100 lines.

Comment: @hek2mgl awk would do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk '/Start/ {f=1} /End/ {print;f=0;}f' file | awk -v RS="End" -v ORS="End" '/930939023/'
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 id: 930939023
2014-07-01 13:26:07,765 something
2014-07-01 13:26:07,766 End
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 Start
2014-07-01 13:26:07,767 id: 930939023
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 something
2014-07-01 13:26:07,768 End
```